# como interpretar un string como variable php

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, funciones, parsear

pretendo hacer esto:

```
echo $.'variable';
```

por consecuencia de esto:

```
//Solicitamos a la BD todas las id de la tabla categorias
$data = $this->Global_model->get_select_array('idcategoria', 'categoria_tmp', TRUE);            

//rastreamos todo el contenido de data para que de ella surja otra consulta
foreach ($data as $key) 
{
    //Creamos la variable where para definir la busqueda en la BD
    $where = array('id_categoria' => $key['idcategoria']);
    //Consultamos a la BD para conseguir todas las preguntas
    $Preguntas[$key['idcategoria']] = $this->Global_model->get_where('pregunta_tmp', $where, TRUE);             
}

//Extraemos las variables otorgadas por $key['idcategoria']
extract($Preguntas);
```

Ya intente con esto:

```
parse_str($variable); //Pero admite un solo formato
```

Todo esto con la finalidad de interpretar una string como variable:

```
<tbody>
      <?php foreach ($.'variable' as $key => $value): ?>

      <?php endforeach ?>
</tbody>
```

Entoces la pregunta es ¿Como puedo interpretar un string como variable en php?

Comment: Una string como variable se interpreta así, creo yo: `$strVariable="Una string como variable";` ¿o te refieres a otra cosa? Si es otra cosa con `parse_str`, sería: `parse_str($variable, $arr);` y luego lees el array: `foreach ($arr as $k=>$v){echo $k." -> ".$v;}`   Pero todo eso dependerá de lo que recibes, ya que si recibes un array no tienes que hacer nada, solamente recorrerlo.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, puedes ver que realice cambios para mejorar la comprension por otro lado tu sugerencia no me ha ayudado ya que la funcion `parse_str($str);` recibe un string con este formato `$str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";` lo que realmente busco es interpretar un string como si fuera una variable entrante

Comment: No se entiende del todo, pero si tú quieres leer esto: `first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz`, con este código: `$str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";
parse_str($str,$arr);
foreach ($arr as $k=>$v){    
    if (is_array($v)){
        foreach ($v as $kk=>$vv){
            echo $kk. " -> ".$vv.PHP_EOL;
        }   
    }else{
        echo $k. " -> ".$v.PHP_EOL;
    }
}` tendrás esta salida: `first -> value
0 -> foo bar
1 -> baz` no sé si es eso lo que buscas.

Answer (score 2):

A ver si te sirve lo siguiente:

```
$str = 'Hola mundo';
$variable = 'str';

echo ${ $variable };
```

En el *echo* estoy pasándole un string para componer el nombre de la variable, esto es pasándolo entre las llaves. He definido previamente la variable, para que no de un error de indefinido.
No se si es lo que estas buscando.
Si quieres componer las variables dinámicamente, igual, entre las llaves:

```
$arr = array();
for ( $i= 0; $i < 10; $i++ ) {

    ${ 'var' . $i } = $i;
    $arr[ $i ] = ${ 'var' . $i };
}
print_r( $arr );
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) donde puedes acceder a una variable utilizando un string:

```
<?php
$q = "hola mundo";
echo ${'q'};// hola mundo

?>
```

Por lo que en tu caso seria:

```
 <?php foreach (${'variable'} as $key => $value): ?>

  <?php endforeach ?>
```

Aunque la documentacion da una advertenecia:

> La diferenciación adicional de una propiedad de variable que es una
>   matriz tiene una semántica diferente entre PHP 5 y PHP 7. La guía de
>   migración de PHP 7.0 incluye más detalles sobre los tipos de
>   expresiones que han cambiado y cómo colocar llaves para evitar
>   ambigüedades.

Por lo que esta a decision tuya si utilizarlo o no.

Comment: Gracias eso necesitaba relamente, le agradezco por su tiempo espero le sirva mi puntaje

Comment: @GorawenChiplex, si esta respuesta respondió tu pregunta, recuerda [aceptar la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.